# Using NetBeans to connect to a serial port.

Tags: netbeans, bluetooth, serial-port, arduino-uno

I need my Arduino to do a task only when the button on keyboard is continuously pressed. Are there any methods to do that? I am using a bluetooth module to send the data and reading the data through serial port. 
The only method I found to do this to create my own NetBeans program to do it..  I know the basics of NetBeans and can create the design of the application but I am not sure of which code to place at which button..  Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I need my Arduino to do a task only when the button on keyboard is continuously pressed.////////

Try HIGH level "interrupt" function

Answer (score 0):

Use serial port libraries to connect to arduino board. you have jar files that can communicate with netbeans try it